# Python - decoding bytes in struct

Tags: python, struct, byte, pyserial

I am building a parser, and I kinda new to this.
I have problem with decoding specific bytes, they always return same int(and they shouldn't) so I must doing it wrong.

```
byte = ser.read(1)
byte += ser.read(ser.inWaiting())

a = 0 
for i in byte:    
    if i == 0x04:
        value = struct.unpack("<h", bytes([i, a]))[0]
        print (value)
```

I recive bytes like this:

```
b'\xaa\x04\x80\x02\xff\xfb\x83\xaa\xaa\x04\x80\
```

And I need to decode packet 0x04. I am using Python 3.6

Answer (score 0):

Try something like :

```
value = int.from_bytes(byte, byteorder='little')
```